# CompileError: Unconsumed column names

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a conditional that takes care of updating or deleting a model based on changes on a model and an operation.

```
if change.operation == 'UPDATE':
    db.query(model).filter_by(id=change.old_record_id).update(change.new)
elif change.operation == 'DELETE':
    db.query(model).filter_by(id=change.old_record_id).delete()

db.commit()
```

When my code reaches this point it gives:
`sqlalchemy.exc:CompileError: Unconsumed column names: subscribers`

I am declaring my engine in this function:

```
def make_session(connection_string):
    engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=False, convert_unicode=True,
                           pool_size=20, max_overflow=20)
    Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    return Session, engine
```

**Full traceback**

The error points to the line 2 of my example, where the update happens

```
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2851, in update
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 897, in exec_
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 995, in _do_exec
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1021, in execute
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 841, in execute
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 322, in _execute_on_connection
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 931, in _execute_clauseelement
File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 493, in compile
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 499, in _compiler
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 395, in __init__
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 199, in __init__
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 222, in process
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 80, in _compiler_dispatch
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 1814, in visit_update
File ".../site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2225, in _get_colparams
```

Comment: Where in the world are you getting this traceback from? A typical Python traceback looks more like https://gist.github.com/cde927a49804ec9944dd7d92ade3667d - Also, the only references in this traceback are to SQLAlchemy code, unless `"<string>", line 1, in <lambda>` references your code. That seems super sketchy though.

Comment: You're probably passing garbage to [`update()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update). It expects a dictionary of attribute names, mapped attributes or SQL expressions as keys and literal values or sql expressions as values. Unless `change.new` happens to be exactly that, but we cannot know since you've not included an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).